# Flutter | Changing pop animation after pushing

Tags: flutter, animation, navigation

I'm using GoRouter in my Flutter App. My home page is a ShellRoute with 4 child routes and a bottom navigation bar to switch between them. I want to animate those subpages like a TabBarView: if I go from a lower index in the tab bar to a higher one, I want the current page to pop with a slide animation to the left and push the new one with a slide animation from the right. If I go from a higher index to a lower one, I want the current page to pop with a slide animation to the right and push the new one with a slide animation from the left. Just like a horizontal swipe or carousel.

Problem is, I can not find information about it. I tried setting the pop animation using the `secondaryAnimation` in the `transitionBuilder` from the `CustomTransitionPage`, but it is locked in once I push the page. I do not know how to pop the page when I push it, only when it's going to pop.

It's there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks